# Postman: How to use global variable defined in Pre-request Script in Tests Script

Tags: api, postman

I have defined one global variable in a Pre-request Script.

I want to compare this global variable with variable  present in the response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the warning message says, you're running a very old version of Postman and it's probably the chrome extension.

This is now several major versions behind and the `pm.*` functionality is not included in that old version of the chrome extension.

Download the native application and start using the newest version of Postman. By not doing this, you're missing out on so many new features.

Answer (score 0):

As @Danny mentioned, it is recommended to update to the latest version.

Now to your question, if you want to compare the global variable with workkard_number present in response, you need to first parse the response and get the workkard_number in it, which you can then compare with your global variable. You could try something like this in your test script:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var responseWorkkardNumber = jsonData.wokkard_number;
```

You can retreive the workkard_number in the response like this(assuming that your response is a json with "workkard_number" as a key in it. Then you can compare it as follows:

```
tests["workkard_numbers are equal"] = responseWorkkardNumber === globals.workkard_number;
```

or

```
tests["workkard_numbers are equal"] = responseWorkkardNumber === pm.globals.get("workkard_number");
```

Also note - "Warning - Environment and global variables will always be stored as strings. If you're storing objects/arrays, be sure to JSON.stringify() them before storing, and JSON.parse() them while retrieving." - https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments

Comment: Thanks, now this is working fine after installing latest postman application